# How to get data in Joomla from  request string

Tags: php

if i have link :  index.php?view=article&id=59:**blue-love**&catid=36:**tui-sach-hang-hieu**&Itemid=1

How can i get the Bold data ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$array = explode(':', $_GET['id']);
$myID = $array[1]; 

$array = explode(':', $_GET['catid']);
$myCATID = $array[1];
```